# Элемент не возвращается на исходную позицию (translateX)

Tags: transform

Элемент с классом .loupe не возвращается на исходное положение при нажатии на крестик

```js
$(".loupe").on("click", function() {
  $(this).css({
    "-webkit-transform": "translateX(130px)",
    "-ms-transform": "translateX(130px)",
    "transform": "translateX(130px)",
    "opacity": "0"
  });

  $(".search, .close").css({
    "opacity": "1"
  });
});

$(".close").on("click", function() {
  $(".loupe").css({
    "-webkit-transform": "translateX(-130px)",
    "-ms-transform": "translateX(-130px)",
    "transform": "translateX(-130px)",
    "opacity": "1"
  });

  $(".search, .close").css({
    "opacity": "0"
  });
  $(".container").css({
    "top": "40%"
  });

  $(".reference").remove();
  $(".search").val("");
})
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #1da362;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.search-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.search {
  opacity: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 35px 0 15px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
}
.search,
.close {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.search-form {
  position: relative;
  width: 257px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.loupe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, transform .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s, transform .5s;
}
.loupe:before,
.loupe:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow .25s;
  transition: box-shadow .25s;
}
.loupe:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px #333 solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.loupe:after {
  width: 3px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: #333;
  top: 29px;
  left: 33px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.loupe:hover:before,
.loupe:hover:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
.close {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.close:before,
.close:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.close:before {
  width: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.close:after {
  width: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transition: top .5s;
  transition: top .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <form class="search-form">
      <input type="text" class="search">
      <span class="close"></span>
    </form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" style="display: none;">
    <span class="loupe"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`translate` рассчитывается от физического положения элемента, а не от текущего.

Т.е. было `translate:0`, стало `translate:130` - чтобы вернуть на прежнее место - надо снова установить `0`.

```js
$(".loupe").on("click", function() {
  $(this).css({
    "-webkit-transform": "translateX(130px)",
    "-ms-transform": "translateX(130px)",
    "transform": "translateX(130px)",
    "opacity": "0"
  });

  $(".search, .close").css({
    "opacity": "1"
  });
});

$(".close").on("click", function() {
  $(".loupe").css({
    "-webkit-transform": "translateX(0px)",
    "-ms-transform": "translateX(0px)",
    "transform": "translateX(0px)",
    "opacity": "1"
  });

  $(".search, .close").css({
    "opacity": "0"
  });
  $(".container").css({
    "top": "40%"
  });

  $(".reference").remove();
  $(".search").val("");
})
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #1da362;
}
a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.search-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.search {
  opacity: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 35px 0 15px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
}
.search,
.close {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.search-form {
  position: relative;
  width: 257px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.loupe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: block;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s, transform .5s;
  transition: opacity .5s, transform .5s;
}
.loupe:before,
.loupe:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow .25s;
  transition: box-shadow .25s;
}
.loupe:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px #333 solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.loupe:after {
  width: 3px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: #333;
  top: 29px;
  left: 33px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.loupe:hover:before,
.loupe:hover:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
.close {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.close:before,
.close:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.close:before {
  width: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.close:after {
  width: 2px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transition: top .5s;
  transition: top .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <form class="search-form">
      <input type="text" class="search">
      <span class="close"></span>
    </form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" style="display: none;">
    <span class="loupe"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```